# Compile a p4 file in mininet

Tags: mininet, topology, p4-lang

I have a custom topology `custom.py` and I wrote a `p4file.p4` file. The problem is that I don't know how to use the `p4file.p4` into mininet with my topology.

For instance, in this github repository (https://github.com/p4lang/tutorials/tree/master/exercises/basic) they use the `make run` command to compile the p4 file, to start the topology and configure all the hosts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the P4-Utils library to define a custom topology and run a p4 file on each switch. The process is pretty simple and explained well in their [documentation](https://nsg-ethz.github.io/p4-utils/usage.html).